# React Hook Test with useDispatch and useSelector

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, enzyme

React Hook has been released for a while but I still cannot find standard test method for testing the `useSelector()` and `useDispatch()` hooks, for example, I have a simple component

```
const TestComponent = () => {
  const currentUserId = useSelector(state => {
    return state.userId;
  });
  const currentUserName = useSelector(state => {
    return state.userName;
  });
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const updateUsername = (id, name) => { dispatch(updateUsername(id, name)) };

  return (
     <span>
      <UserForm userId={currentUserId} userName={currentUserName} onChange={() => {updateUsername}} />
    </span>
  )
}
```

How could I write the test case for `useSelector()` and `useDispatch()` that I would like to verify:

1) When I initialize the react hook component with some mock up state, my `currentUserId` inside the component would be same the mocked up ``state.userId` ?

2) When I simulate the `onChange` event on `UserForm` component, that my `dispatch(updateUsername(id, name))` should be called once? Along with my `state.name` would be updated with mockup update user name?